# Should we make a "Maximum" or "Absolute" tag?

Tags: feature-request

I am thinking specifically of questions like [these two](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/62/11) [2048 puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48/11), [this chess puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/7/11), and [this Sudoku puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2/11).  They are all asking for an absolute, a single absolute case.  I do believe we should have a tag for such questions.  My question for meta is: *what should we call this tag?*

My suggestions are:

1. [min-max](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/min-max)  These problems are asking for either a minimum or maximum number of solutions/pieces/moves, etc.
2. [absolute](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute)  This is perhaps slightly more general, and could apply better to questions such as [this question about river-crossing puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/91/11).

Edit: I think this discussion is far less relevant than the one [over here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/155/11).

Answer (score 1):

I think [min-max](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/min-max) is a bad name for this tag, since it's also the name of a solving technique.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see what this tag is supposed to convey. Tags are supposed to indicate what the question is about — most tag names should be valid filler in “this question is about ____”.

Why would anyone subscribe to the [absolute](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute) tag (or whatever you want to call it? Why would anyone ignore that tag? Why would it be useful for searches (“I want a single absolute case” wouldn't be a good reason, since this case could be mentioned as part of a thread that isn't focused on that absolute case)?

Read [the death of meta tags](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Although your proposal isn't exactly a “meta tag”, it shares the same problems. It isn't useful to classify questions.

Comment: I guess it is similar to those meta-tags, but not entirely.  In the respect that it has to be able to stand on its own, how are the "solutions" or "tips" tags valid?

Comment: @Xynariz [tag:tips] is a horrible tag, it's completely meaningless. I've submitted edits to remove it. [tag:solutions] is not necessarily bad — it means that the question is about solving as opposed to setting a puzzle.

Comment: That's fine, but why did you leave the comment on this unrelated question?  Are you claiming that tips is a bad tag?  If so, I won't disagree with you - I approved your edits.  But, by definition, solutions is also a meta tag (it can't stand alone on a question).  I suppose we could have required tags (enforced by software ideally, us far less ideally) that every question have Solutions, Puzzle-Creation, or something....

Comment: @Xynariz I hadn't noticed the `tips` tag before. You seemed to be using its existence as an argument — well, it shouldn't exist. [tag:solutions] is more ambiguous: it can't stand on its own, but it does categorize the topic of the question (whereas [tag:tips] only categorizes the formulation of the question, and very subjectively at that).

Comment: Ah, now I see why you talked about tips.  (I wasn't thinking.)  I used `tips` as an example of existing tags describing _types_ of problems.  In my opinion, if one should exist, many should.  As I mentioned in the last comment, I think such tags should either be required or non-existent.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Xynariz [tag:tips] doesn't describe a type of problem. I think [tag:solutions] requires [a discussion of its own](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/155/is-the-solutions-tag-useful).